# Changing value in a single row by the name of the column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How to change a value in a single row, when I've got the name of the value from another column (same row)?

Example: I've got the that data frame:

```
     id      sex    age
1    k.8   female    17
```

I know the id, I want to change age in this particular row.

Comment: Please paste the code you tried till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call that table x

```
x[x$id == "k.8", "age"] <- 3
```

you should look into what `[]` and `[[]]` do